# nodejs v5.10.1 cannot get my host address anymore?

Tags: linux, node.js, express

Why the latest version of nodejs (v5.10.1) cannot get my host address anymore?

express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "Hello World!" on the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log(server.address());

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

result:

```
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 3000 }
Example app listening at http://:::3000
```

It should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

I am on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, maybe you will see something like

:80

and then

::80

actually this one have a pattern like this:

**host:port** IPv4

**host::port** IPv6

127.0.0.1:80 means that using IPv4, listening in 127.0.0.1 in port 80

:80 means that using IPv4 ,listening on all address in port 80

127.0.0.1::80 means that using IPv6, listening in 127.0.0.1 in port 80

and so on.

so, the ::3000 means listening to IPv6  in port 3000

These configuration was done under these variable

```
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;
```

you can just change the value of these variable to "127.0.0.1" and "80" and see what happens, but most likely your machine still using IPv6 there, if you want to change to IPv4 for your machine, change the setting of your machine under:

**Windows**: control panel -> network and sharing center -> (your network) -> properties -> setup the IPv4

**Linux**: i dont have linux machine to test this, but the syntax should be using ifconfig or ipconfig depends on your linux, please refer for something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34093/static-ipv4-ipv6-configuration-on-centos-6-2

**Mac**: i dont have mac machine also, should be the same with linux so try to do the same also

Comment: im on linux by the way

Comment: You wont see :80, that's an example to explaining the : and by default http protocol will use port 80, https 443, so http://127.0.0.1 will be same as 127.0.0.1:80

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i solved it acessing like an array:

server.address()["port"]

Here a example:

```js
export const onError = (server: Server) => {
    console.log(server.address()["port"])
    return (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException): void => {
        let port: number | string = server.address()["port"];
        if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;
        let bind = (typeof port === 'string') ? `pipe ${port}` : `port ${port}`;
        switch(error.code) {
            case 'EACCES': 
                console.error(`${bind} requires elevated privileges`);
                process.exit(1);  
                break;
            case 'EADDRINUSE':
                console.error(`${bind} is already in use`);
                process.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                throw error;
        }
    }
}
```